# PropertyGrid does not list member class members

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I have:

```
class Foo1
{
    private string name1;
    [CategoryAttribute("Category1")]
    public string Name1
    {
        get { return name1; }
        set { name1 = value; }
    }
}
```

and

```
class Foo2
{
    private string name2;
    [CategoryAttribute("Category2")]
    public string Name2
    {
        get { return name2; }
        set { name2 = value; }
    }
}
```

If I have Foo2 derived from Foo1 and set Foo2 as SelectedObject in a PropertyGrid, I will have members of Foo1 listed, but if I have Foo1 member in Foo2, Foo1 members are not listed. Is there any way to list members of Foo1 in the PropertyGrid for the second case?

Thanks!

Comment: I started using C# to make simple things in a simple way. I wasted a lot of time trying to understand the language and integrating things made in C++ with C#. It seems that this language makes impossible customization(almost). It has a terrible interface for all classes. Thanks for the help I received here in the last weeks, but I will continue using C++. I didn't see any advantage of using C# so I'll stop using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need typeconverter to achieve this. Take a look at this : [Getting the Most Out of the .NET Framework PropertyGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx#usingpropgrid_topic6) at section **Support for Custom Types**

Answer (score 3):

try to specify a typeconverter for Foo2. Now Foo2's members should be listed in Foo1 object's property.

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
class Foo2
{
    private string name2;
    [CategoryAttribute("Category2")]
    public string Name2
    {
        get { return name2; }
        set { name2 = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: In case when Foo1 has a property of Foo2 type.